# Is there an example of the "linprog" package using multiple sets of data and optimizing between the sets?

Tags: r, linear-programming

I have three sets of data associated with three ranches.  Each ranch maximizes profit (net margin) as a function of six landuse options (including option to be paid for landuses with smaller water usage): two irrigation options for the flood plain (bottom lands) and four irrigation options for above the flood plain (bench lands).  The decision variable is acres put into production between the six landuse options and associated net margins subject to five constraints: "<=" maxbtmland, "<=" maxbenchland, ">=" water savings, ">=" min acres of wetlands, ">=" min stream flow.

I use "linprog" package to solve for one ranch, but I am having trouble figuring out how to loop through three ranches. I would also like to generalize the code so I can run sensitivity analysis on constraints.  Any ideas? Examples online? Here is my baseline code (ecological constraints set to zero) for one of my study sites:

```
require(linprog)
## Production activities
cvec <- c(124,193,69,156,49,-4) # gross margins
names(cvec) <- c("FloodBtm0","FloodBtm1","FloodBench0","FloodBench1","PivotBench0","PivotBench1")
## Constraints (quasi-fix factors)
bvec <- c(2220,580,0,0,0) # endowment
names(bvec) <- c("BtmLand","BenchLand","Flow","Wetlands","WaterSavings")
## Needs of Production activities
Amat <- rbind( c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,1,1,1,1),
               c(1.8,1.9,1.2,1.6,0.7,0.3),
               c(0.77,0.32,0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0.68,0,0.68,0,1.08))
## Maximize the gross margin
res <- solveLP( cvec, bvec, Amat, maximum = TRUE,  const.dir = c("<=", "<=", ">=", ">=",">="))
## print the results
print( res )
```

Comment: please add some tags to provide context ... this appears to be R language.

Comment: Are you just trying to solve three independent LPs, or are there relationships between the three ranches? What are the quantities that vary ranch-by-ranch?

Comment: Each ranch has a unique Amat, cvec, and bvec (so all inputs vary).  The decision variable is the quantity of acres (x) in each landuse (names(cvec)) so that will vary ranch-by-ranch as well. The setup above is for an individual ranch.  However, I would like to relate them by setting additional constraints on the **total** "Flow", "Wetlands", and "WaterSavings" between the three sites; in order to see where a unit of acre would be put into production between the three study sites as a total wetland min. constraint were to increase across all three study sites.